# Exclude sonar classes in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, sonarqube

I'm trying to exclude classes from a specific package from my gradle project so that sonar won't parse them.

Seeing the [sonar documentation for gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/), in the build.gradle file I have added the following:

```
 sonarqube {
     properties {
         property 'sonar.exclusions', "**/ws/**/"
     }
 }
```

So that when passing the sonar in the project all the classes that are inside the / ws / package exclude them, but when executing the sonar, the classes have not been excluded.

Is there a way to exclude packets in the gradle so that they are not parsed by sonar?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you need to exclude `"**/ws/**"` instead of `"**/ws/**/"`.

Comment: Or maybe `"**/ws/**/*"`

Comment: Hi!

We have also tried with property `"sonar.exclusions", "**/ws/**/*.Java"` and sonar has continued executing them :(

Comment: Why with a capital J?

Comment: Sorry, the format was changed when pasting, the "j" is lowercase

`"sonar.exclusions", "**/ws/**/*.java"`

Answer (score -1):

try something like

```
 sonarqube {
     properties {
         property "sonar.language", "java"
         property 'sonar.exclusions', "**/ws/**/*.java"
     }
 }
```

Comment: `sonar.language` has been removed a long time ago.

Comment: Hello we have tried and it has not worked:

`sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property 'sonar.exclusions', "**/ws/**/*.java"
    }
}`


We have also tried the following in the build.gradle and it still does not exclude the classes:

`jacocoTestReport {
    executionData integrationTest, test
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: '**/ws/**/*.java')
        })
    }
}`